# How to use SUM with DISTINCT function togather

Tags: mysql, sum, distinct

Is there any way by which i can SUM(value) of ColA (ColA is repeating in each ROW) based on DISTINCT(value) of ColB?

My Data Table is:

```
+-------+-------+------+--------+
| State | KEY_ID| Score| STATUS |
+-------+-------+------+--------+
|  ABCD |   11  |   20 |   1    |
|  ABCD |   11  |   30 |   1    |
|  ABCD |   13  |   40 |   1    |
|  DEFG |   21  |   10 |   1    |
|  DEFG |   21  |   25 |   1    |
|  DEFG |   23  |   15 |   1    |
+-------+-------+------+--------+
```

& wanted output like :

```
+-------+-------+------+--------+
| State | KEY_ID| Score| STATUS |
+-------+-------+------+--------+
|  ABCD |   11  |   50 |   1    |
|  ABCD |   13  |   40 |   1    |
|  DEFG |   21  |   35 |   1    |
|  DEFG |   23  |   15 |   1    |
+-------+-------+------+--------+
```

but not want to use GROUP BY function & OVER() in not working in my MySQL version 8.0.28

Comment: it looks like you need aggregate functions. Please review manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html , though to be sure you should provide sample data and desired outcome as text

Answer (score 0):

You want a simple GROUP BY query to [aggregate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions-and-modifiers.html) your scores. [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3nmwWkTVnmf8FEi12J6Jt7/0).

```
SELECT State, KEY_ID,
       SUM(Score) Score,
       STATUS
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY State, KEY_ID, STATUS
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP_BY` (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) on `KEY_ID`

like this query

```
SELECT State, KEY_ID, SUM(Score), STATUS FROM data_table GROUP BY KEY_ID;
```